# Can I use a custom command in the CMD to run python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I would like to run my python script by a custom command

Previously, we would have to run

```
python hello.py
```

For example, I would type:
`hello`
in my command prompt
then my computer will run my `hello.py`

Comment: Read:  https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2014/12/04/better-python-integration-in-windows-shebangs-and-version-selectors/ or Google "python windows shebang"

Comment: For Windows, type `ftype /?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple batch file and place it in a folder that is in your system path variable.

Name it `$Py.bat`

```bat
@Echo off
If not "%~1" == "" (
 python "%~1.py" 2> nul || (Echo/"%~1.py" failed to execute correctly or was not found.)
) Else Echo/Filename required.
```

Then run it in `cmd.exe` using:

```bat
 $Py hello
```

---

Another approach would to be to create a macro using setx

```bat
 SetX run "python F.py"
```

*SetX adds the variable with it's value to the registry. It is not available in the Session in which it is created, nor in any child environment of that Session.*

Execute by expanding the variable with substring modification replacing `F` with the filename:

```bat
%run:F=hello%
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two pieces to this. The first is the `PATHEXT` environment variable that stores a list of the file extensions for operation system to execute. When running a command line that does not contain an extension, the system uses the value of this environment variable to determine which extensions to look for and in what order, such as .com first, follow by .exe, .bat, .cmd, which happens to be the default value stored in the PathExt by Windows. On my computer:

```
C:\>echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.py;.pyw
```

If `.py` is not part of your PATHEXT environment variable, you can add it by right-mouse clicking on the `Start` box in the lower left corner of your screen and the clicking on `Settings`. When the new window comes up, type `environment` in the search box and then click on one of the Edit choices:
[image]

This now allows you to type in `hello` instead of `hello.py` at the command prompt. Referring back to my environment variable, if there were two files `hello.bat` and `hello.py` the system would choose `hello.bat` because the .BAT extension is listed before the .py extension (everything is case insensitive). But the second piece of the puzzle is associating the Python interpreter with the .py extension so that the system knows how to run that type of file. Enter the Windows `ftype` command. This produces a list of mappings of file type extensions and the programs used to launch those extensions. On my computer, one of the lines listed is:

```
Python.CompiledFile="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*
```

I installed Python using a standard installation from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) and when I did I installed the optional [Python launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), which is the "C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" you see above. This launcher supports multiple Python versions and allows you to control which Python version will execute your Python program based on the *shebang* that you code as the first line of your program. But generally, when you install Python under Windows, an association is made between the .py file type and the Python interpreter. If you do not have this association, you can look for your Python file in an Explorer window, right-mouse click on it and then choose Open With:

[image]

My options show Python since I already have the association. In your case it would probably be missing, so you would pick "Choose Another App" and then if you still don't see Python in the list you would choose "Look for another app on this PC" and then navigate to the Python interpreter. Either way, be sure to click on the box labeled "Always use this app to open .py files":

[image]